# Any way to make your crew stop attacking a system?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

So I have a game paused right now. Here's the **dire** situation:

- Enemy: Auto-scout, all rooms seperated from each other, ONE hull
  point left.
- Me: Teleporter on cooldown, two fully leveled rockmen inside the enemy ship attacking a system.

So there's my dilemma: if my rockmen continue to attack the system in the room they are in, they will destroy it, dealing 1 damage to the enemy ship, causing it to explode and kill both of my crew members inside. I can't teleport them back because my teleport is on cooldown, and I can't move them to another room because all of the rooms are disconnected.

Am I just screwed, or is there some magical keystroke to make my rockmen turn passive?

Comment: It's bloodlust. Embrace it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've been in a similar situation, and no, there is no way to stop them attacking. I've always wondered what goes through their heads in these situations. Probably something like this:

> **Me**: "No, stop attacking, one more hitpoint and that ship'll be torn
>   apart!" 
>   <Mantis 1 turns to Mantis 2>
>   **M1**: "We have a chance here to do something great, something profound here today" 
>   **M2**: <Smiles Grimly> "I hope the Federation dedicates a statue on some blasted rock for us" 
>   <They embrace> 
>   **M1**: "It has been good knowing you brother" 
>   <They turn and deal the final blow to the shield generator. As the ship blows up around them they look out a nearby window and see the Kestrel - dodging past a few missiles as a Beam Drone continually attempts to break through the shields, and they know that their sacrifice will be remembered.>

Comment: Damn it, I lost a Crystal to this mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

If you order them to move to another room, they'll stop attacking and start walking.

If you want them to stay in that room for some particular reason, then an approach I've used in the past is to order them to a different room on the left, then a second later order them to a room on the right, and back and forth.  This way they're constantly in motion (not attacking anything) but don't actually go anywhere.

In your case, I would just send them to an empty room to wait for the teleporter to recharge.  Or, if all the auto-scout's rooms had systems in, I'd keep them moving from one end of the ship to the other, until the teleporter was ready to bring them back.

Comment: If you notice he stated that its an autoscout where all the rooms are separated so there's no way to order the units to move anywhere.  Your strategy would work though if there were any interconnected rooms.

Comment: Ah - you're right, I missed that.  I was thinking of the alternative layout.

Comment: I'm minded to still leave this answer up in case it helps anyone else who sees the question title and misses the details (like me).  Sadly the OP's game is a lost cause by this point anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Ionizing the system may stun them and stop the attack. A good thing to use with Lanius boarders, btw, everyone is stunned but O2 is still drained from the system.